# What is Vector data structure

Tags: vector, data-structures, abstract-data-type

I know Vector in C++ and Java, it's like dynamic Array, but I can't find any general definition of Vector data structure. So what is Vector? Is Vector a general data structure(like arrray, stack, queue, tree,...) or it just a data type depending on language?

Comment: It's most  certainly a matter of opinion.

Comment: It's not obvious to me what you are trying to connote by "general data structure" and "just a data type".

Answer (score 39):

The word "vector" as applied to computer science/programming is borrowed from math, which can make the use confusing (even your question could be on multiple subjects).

The simplest example of vectors in math is the number line, used to teach elementary math (especially to help visualize negative numbers, subtraction of negative numbers, addition of negative numbers, etc).

The vector is a distance and direction from a point. This is why it can confuse the discussion, because a vector data structure COULD be three points, X,Y,Z, in a structure used in 3D graphics engines, or a 2D point (just X,Y). In that context, the subtraction of two such points results in a vector - the vector describes how far and in what direction to travel from one of the source operands to the other.

This applies to storage, like stl vectors or Java vectors, in that storage is represented as a distance from an address (where a memory address is similar to a point in space, or on a number line).

The concept is related to arrays, because arrays could be the storage allocated for a vector, but I submit that the vector is a larger concept than the array. A vector must include the concept of distance from a starting point, and if you think of the beginning of an array as the starting point, the distance to the end of the array is it's size.

So, the data structure representing a vector must include the size, whereas an array doesn't have storage to include the size, it's assumed by the way it's allocated. That is to say, if you dynamically allocate an array, there is no data structure storing the size of that array, the programmer must assume to know that size, or store it in a some integer or long.

The vector data structure (say, the design of a vector class) DOES need to store the size, so at a minimum, there would be a starting point (the base of an array, or some address in memory) and a distance from that point indicating size.

That's really "RAM" oriented, though, in description, because there's one more point not yet described which must be part of the data describing the vector - the notion of element size. If a vector represents bytes, and memory storage is typically measured in bytes, an address and a distance (or size) would represent a vector of bytes, but nothing else - and that's a very machine level thinking. A higher thought, that of some structure, has it's own size - say, the size of a float or double, or of a structure or class in C++. Whatever the element size is, the memory required to store N of them requires that the vector data structure have some knowledge of WHAT it's storing, and how large that thing is. This is why you'd think in terms of "a vector of strings" or "a vector of points". A vector must also store an element size.

So, a basic vector data structure must have:

An address (the starting point)

An element size (each thing it stores is X bytes long)

A number of elements stored (how many elements times element size is 'minimum' storage size).

One important "assumption" made in this simple 3 item list of entries in the vector data structure is that the address is allocated memory, which must be freed at some point, and is to be guarded against access beyond the end of the vector.

That means there's something missing. In order to make a vector class work, there is a recognizable difference between the number of ITEMS stored in the vector, and the amount of memory ALLOCATED for that storage. Typically, as you might realize from the use of vector from the STL, it may "know" it has room to store 10 items, but currently only has 2 of them.

So, a working vector class would ALSO have to store the amount of memory allocation. This would be how it could dynamically extend itself - it would now have sufficient information to expand storage automatically.

Thinking through just how you would make a vector class operate gives you the structure of data required to operate a vector class.

Comment: Your answer is very detailed and helpful, can you show me a reference document for your answer(vector data structure in computer science, not only in c++) or it's just your opinion and experience?

Comment: Ouch! That was a stream of consciousness post out of experience, but you'll find something along these lines in several texts on data structures. I haven't had a book or reference on the subject in my hands in over 20 years (I've been a developer since '81), so an exact title escapes me. Also, I might extend, that STL vectors may have static constants or perhaps 'tunable' members indicating expansion options - that is, for example, some vectors may do well to expand 10 items at a time, while others may as well expand 1000 items at a time.

Comment: Sorry but I still didn't understand anything.

Answer (score 20):

It's an array with dynamically allocated space, everytime you exceed this space new place in memory is allocated and old array is copied to the new one. Old one is freed then.

Moreover, vector usually allocates more memory, than it needs to, so it does not have to copy all the data, when new element is added.

It may seem, that lists then are much much better, but it's not necessarily so. If you do not change your vector often (in terms of size), then computer's cache memory functions much better with vectors, than lists, because they are continuus in memory space. Disadvantage is when you have large vector, that you need to expand. Then you have to agree to copy large amount of data to another space in memory.

What's more. You can add new data to the end and to the front of the vector. Because Vector's are array-like, then every time you want to add element to the beginning of the vector all the array has to be copied. Adding elements to the end of vector is far more efficient. There's no such an issue with linked lists.

Vector gives random access to it's internal kept data, while lists,queues,stacks do not.

Answer (score 1):

1. Vectors are the same as dynamic arrays with the ability to resize
   itself automatically when an element is inserted or deleted.
2. Vector elements are placed in contiguous storage so that they can be
   accessed and traversed using iterators.
3. In vectors, data is inserted at the end.